# Error using ORM to import a new table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an existing php web app written using symfony2 and doctrine2.  I added a table to the database.  Now, I want the ORM to write the php classes for me.  I tried doing this:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

I also tried this:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import SomeBundle annotation
```

Both of them throw this error:

```
[ErrorException]

Warning: class_parents(): Class SomeClass does not exist 
and could not be loaded in C:\wamp\www\vac\vendor\
gedmo-doctrine-extensions\lib\Gedmo\Mapping\
ExtensionMetadataFactory.php line 80
```

Any ideas on what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. delete all your entities along with your Entity Folder.
2. delete all orm files with your orm folder.
3. then try to create orm and entity files from your db having new table.

   a.`$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/YourDir/YourBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force`

   b.`$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import YourDirYourBundle annotation`

   c.`$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities YourDirYourBundle`

Try this.

Comment: I imagine this would work.  But, the entities have been modified, so, I would lose code.  I imagine the correct way to use the ORM is to extend the created entities and specialize them that way.  That is, never edit generated code.  With that said, I will mark this as the answer for others.  If someone finds this is not the answer, speak up.